# How do I adjust the sensitivity of Delphi gesture recognition?

Tags: delphi, touch, gesture, gesture-recognition

Delphi gesture recognition is too sensitive.  a "swipe" (standard) gesture can be extremely short, making it too easy to accidentally be doing something the app considers to be a swipe.

i noticed that the definition in Vcl.Touch.Gestures.pas suggests a width of 200 but i think that's just to give it "something" (because the gesture can clearly be much shorter than 200).

```
  PDefaultLeft: array[0..1] of TPoint = ((X:200; Y:0), (X:0; Y:0));

  CDefaultLeft: TStandardGestureData = (
    GestureID: sgiLeft;
    Options: [goUniDirectional];
    Deviation: 30;
    ErrorMargin: 20);
```

Anyone have any suggestions how this could be made less "accepting"?

i wonder if the answer is to use a different recognition engine...

Comment: Create your own custom gesture and ignore this one?

Comment: @WarrenP y'know, that does actually seem to work better!  thank you.

Comment: No problemo, dude! I'm about to try some of this myself. (Microsoft Surface Pro + touchscreen + Delphi App = Gestures fun!)